# Gather/Collect output files from automated (unit) test as test evidence under C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to create a set of automated tests for testing an application, which is mainly non-UI/non-WEB. The tests shall basically start the actual application, feed some data through its interfaces and inspect/verify its output/responses. 
Ideally, such tests can be run from the build server and also by any developer on their machine.

Although this this obviously not a unit test, one approach frequently stated is to author such tests similar to unit tests in C# (i.e. create a test project with a number of [TestMethod]s, etc.). This works generally fine and I can run the tests and see their result (success/fail). For MSTest, the summary is also available in a trx file - good for further processing the test results, e.g. to stash them away in a documentation system.

However, it would be highly desirable to gather/collect additional files that are being produced while each test is run - for example log files of the application, output files produced by the application, even performance monitor logs files if the test is done with such aspects monitored.

I could potentially write individual code at the end of each test method to gather such evidence, but that would be not very nice, as all/most tests would want to gather the same or similar files. To write generic code (either a utility function or test cleanup code) I would need to at least know what test method is currently being run, which does not seem to be available (other than scanning through call-stacks, etc.).

Does anyone have any ideas how to approach this? It does not seem to be such an uncommon request, that running tests should result in more than just success/fail. I am not bound to Visual Studio's built-in test runner or (ab)using the unit test framework for system/integration tests - although it would be nice if the solution integrates into Visual Studio somehow.

Comment: To be honest, this is an unusual approach. Normally you would have the unit testing which tests blocks of code and e2e testing which interacts with the app as a user would (e.g. moving mouse and clicking, for web Selenium is used for that). Now with you saying (non Ui / Non Web) i suspect it's a service of sorts. So i would write a suite of methods that create input data (events) and then assert on expected output (which i am guessing is what you've done based on the post).

Comment: Mostly correct. Yes, the application is mainly a service. Yes, the automated tests are more e2e than unit tests. Yes, I have (ab)used Visual Studio's test frame work and runner to write and execute the tests - whether that is the correct approach, I am not sure. Microsoft itself seems to propagate this. Yes, the tests already feed data and use assertions to check the output/responses. All good so far. However QA wants not just success/fail as a result, but more evidence on the run. This is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: With regards to collecting data -> you could use `[TestCleanup]`  in the base class from which all the test classes would derive. You could then use the `TestContext` in the file to get the details of the previous test. You could then inspect ALL logs and locations of potential data and bundle that (e.g. to a file/folder whatever, you can use TestContext.ResultsDirectory or so) and snap the name of the test on it so you can then have a test run artifact folder. This is fairly simple.

Comment: TestContext is a great hint. It gives me information about which test is being run, so I can write a generic [TestCleanup] that gathers all evidence into a file named after the test. I am also currently digging into TestContext.AddResultFile. Looks promising.